# dygraphs: How to move the primary y-axis to right side

Tags: dygraphs

This the graph that I am looking for [range-selector dygraph](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/range-selector)
but instead of having the primary y-axis on left I want it on right side. Is it possible in dygraphs? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by moving all your series to a secondary y-axis (which is always rendered on the right side) and then hiding the primary y-axis.

Example [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/4908/):

```js
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"), data,
               {
                 series: {
                     A: { axis: 'y2' },
                     B: { axis: 'y2' },
                     ...
                 },
                 axes: {
                     y: {
                         drawGrid: false,
                         independentTicks: false
                     },
                     y2: {
                         drawGrid: true,
                         independentTicks: true
                     }
                 }
             });
```

You'll still get a primary y-axis, which you currently have to hide via CSS (at least until [this issue](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/444) is resolved):

```
.dygraph-axis-label-y1 { display: none; }
```

Comment: but the space occupied by primary y-axis after hiding it is same as before. Can we also reduce it?

Comment: drawYAxis: false reduces size from both sides.

Comment: drawY1Axis and drawY2Axis options will be of greater use. thanks

Comment: This method doesn't allow the y2 grid and leaves extra space on the y1 axis for me. To enable the y2 grid (and remove the extra space on the y1 axis), do `y: { drawGrid: true, valueRange: [0, 0], axisLabelWidth: 0, independentTicks: false}, y2: {drawGrid: true, independentTicks: true}`

Answer (score 0):

It sucks, but it works:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".dygraph-axis-label-y")).forEach(function(e) {
  e.parentElement.style.left="800px";
});
```

Run the code AFTER the graphs are generated. Adjust the style directive as needed. I found setting textAlign to left was also helpful.